# Install and configure PHP5 and 7 on same Ubuntu server

Tags: php, webserver, php-7, php-5.5

I have installed both PHP versions **(php5 & php7)** on the same Linux server and it works for me, when I switch the version configuration on system.

Also it shows changes happen in the info.php file in the browser, but in terminal using **php -v** ,it shows only php7 version installed though it works under php5.

how can i correct the version information in php5 while chk in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

When PHP is installed side to side there are different executables for the different versions. When you use a Web Server you choose which version to use via its configuration.

If `php -v` shows PHP 7 try `php5 -v`. If this returns the right version you can use php5 to run any script with php5.

To find out where exactly the PHP executables are use:

```
which php
whereis php
which php7
whereis php7
```